# No data on Parcelable object sent to other activities with other parcelables inside

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm doing an app that needs to pass an object through activities, so to achieve this I've made 3  parcelable classes.

The structure is the following:

> ```
> > List of Quiz:
> >  - int event_id;
> >  - String name;
> >  - String business_unit;
> >  - int functional_area_business;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
> >  - int functional_area_support;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
> >  - List<Quiz> list_quizs;
> >          |
> >          \
> >           -> Quiz:
> >               - int id;
> >               - String title;
> >               - String description;
> >               - int speaker_id;
> >               - String speaker_name;
> >               - List<Answer> list_answers;
> >                        |
> >                        \
> >                         -> Answer:
> >                             - int answer_id;
> >                             - String title;
> >                             - int order;
> >                             - int type;
> >                             - String value;
> >                             - int quiz_parent;
> ```

As you can see, List_Quiz has some variables and a list of Quiz(class), Quiz is the same, some variables and a list of Answers(another class).

I don't know if when I send the main object "List_Quiz" through intents the data sent is the complete tree of List_Quiz with Quiz and with Answers, or only the data stored in the first parcelable class List_Quiz, because I don't get any data from answers in the activity that receives the parcelable object.

My parcelable classes are :

LIST_QUIZ

```
public class List_Quizs implements Parcelable {

    int event_id;
    String name;
    String business_unit;
    int functional_area_business;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
    int functional_area_support;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
    List<Quiz> list_quizs; // MyClass should implement Parcelable properly

    // ==================== Parcelable ====================
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(event_id);
        out.writeString(name);
        out.writeString(business_unit);
        out.writeInt(functional_area_business);
        out.writeInt(functional_area_support);
        out.writeList(list_quizs);
    }

    public List_Quizs() {
    }

    private List_Quizs(Parcel in) {
        event_id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        business_unit = in.readString();
        functional_area_business = in.readInt();
        functional_area_support = in.readInt();
        list_quizs = new ArrayList<Quiz>();
        in.readList(list_quizs, List_Quizs.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<List_Quizs> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<List_Quizs>() {
        public List_Quizs createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new List_Quizs(in);
        }
        public List_Quizs[] newArray(int size) {
            return new List_Quizs[size];
        }
    };

}
```

QUIZ

```
public class Quiz implements Parcelable {

    int id;
    String title;
    String description;
    int speaker_id;
    String speaker_name;
    List<Answer> list_answers;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeInt(speaker_id);
        dest.writeString(speaker_name);
        dest.writeList(list_answers);
    }

    public Quiz(Parcel in) {

        id = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        speaker_id = in.readInt();
        speaker_name = in.readString();
        list_answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
        in.readList(list_answers , Quiz.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public Quiz(){

    }

    //GETTER, SETTERS
    ...
    //

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Quiz> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Quiz>() {
        public Quiz createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Quiz(in);
        }

        public Quiz[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Quiz[size];
        }
    };
}
```

ANSWER

```
public class Answer implements Parcelable {

    int answer_id;
    String title;
    int order;
    int type;
    String value;
    int quiz_parent;

    //GETTERS, SETTERS        

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Answer> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Answer>() {
        public Answer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Answer(in);
        }

        public Answer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Answer[size];
        }
    };
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(answer_id);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeInt(order);
        dest.writeInt(type);
        dest.writeString(value);
        dest.writeInt(quiz_parent);
    }

    public Answer(Parcel in) {
        answer_id = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
        order = in.readInt();
        type = in.readInt();
        value = in.readString();
        quiz_parent = in.readInt();
    }

    public Answer() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got

```
list_answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
in.readList(list_answers , Quiz.class.getClassLoader());
```

on your Quizz class (bad copy-paste ? :p) . It should be

```
list_answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
in.readList(list_answers , Answer.class.getClassLoader());
```